# MPChart xAxis values not aligned

Tags: java, android, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

I am trying to implement grouped MPAndroid Bar chart. I have a group of 2 datasets that i want to display. The problem is that the xaxis values are not center aligned with the bar chart (as per the screenshot). I checked other questions as well and implemented the following answers provided.

I want to make the labels center aligned with the grouped bars.

```
float barSpace = 0.02f;
float groupSpace = 0.3f;
int groupCount = 2;
data.setBarWidth(0.155f);
pvaAmount_chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
pvaAmount_chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + pvaAmount_chart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
pvaAmount_chart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);
pvaAmount_chart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(true);
pvaAmount_chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**When entering groupcount=2 as 2 types of bars:**
[image: when entering groupcount=2 as 2 types of bars]

**When entering groupcount=4 number of grouped charts:**
[image: when entering groupcount=4 number of grouped charts]

Answer (score 0):

i'm doing it like this :

```
String [] values = new String[insert the lenght of your array]
for (int blabla=0;i<values[lenght];blabla++){
String dayOfTheWeek = dateFormat.format(mydate);
vales[blabla] = dayOfTheWeek //in my case
```

}

```
    xAxis.setGranularity(1.0f); //
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(values.length,false); // 
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(values.length,false); // 
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues((ArrayList<String>) stringList)));
```

i'm using :   'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

Comment: I used it but it didnt work. Now the labels are center aligned but bars are not